# How to install Resource package with Anaconda python

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

To install `Resource` package using `pip`, we use the command:

`pip install Resource`

What is the command to install `Resource` package using `conda` ?

Comment: I don't think it is available from any public conda channel. You will have to use `pip`